The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception when i am run my code in server
public async Task<Response<List<string>>> Handle(UploadImageRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     try
     {
         if (request.Files == null || request.Files.Count == 0)
         {
             throw new Exception("No files uploaded.");
         }
         if (request.Watermark == null)
         {
             throw new Exception("Watermark image is missing.");
         }
         var uploadedImagePaths = new List<string>();

         float opacity = ParseOpacity(request.Opacity);

         using (var watermarkStream = new MemoryStream())
         {
             await request.Watermark.CopyToAsync(watermarkStream);
             using (var watermarkImage = Image.FromStream(watermarkStream))
             {
                 foreach (var file in request.Files)
                 {
                     string name = null;
                     try
                     {
                         name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                     }
                     catch
                     {
                         throw new Exception("Name");
                     }
                     if (name != null)
                     {
                         bool gdiPlusInstalled = GdiPlusCheck.IsGdiPlusInstalled();
                         if (gdiPlusInstalled)
                         {
                             
                         }
                         else
                         {

                         }
                         using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                         {
                             await file.CopyToAsync(stream);

                             using (var uploadedImage = Image.FromStream(stream))
                             using (var mergedImage = new Bitmap(uploadedImage.Width, uploadedImage.Height))
                             using (var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(mergedImage))
                             {
                                 graphic.DrawImage(uploadedImage, 0, 0);
                                 graphic.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;

                                 var watermarkAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
                                 watermarkAttributes.SetColorMatrix(new ColorMatrix { Matrix33 = opacity });


                                 var watermarkWidth = (int)(uploadedImage.Width * 0.25);
                                 var watermarkHeight = (int)(watermarkImage.Height * ((float)watermarkWidth / watermarkImage.Width));
                                 var x = request.WaterMarkPosition switch
                                 {
                                     WaterMarkPosition.TopLeft => 0,
                                     WaterMarkPosition.TopRight => uploadedImage.Width - watermarkWidth,
                                     WaterMarkPosition.BottomLeft => 0,
                                     WaterMarkPosition.BottomRight => uploadedImage.Width - watermarkWidth,
                                     WaterMarkPosition.LeftMiddle => 0,
                                     WaterMarkPosition.RightMiddle => uploadedImage.Width - watermarkWidth,
                                     _ => (uploadedImage.Width - watermarkWidth) / 2, 
                                 };

                                 var y = request.WaterMarkPosition switch
                                 {
                                     WaterMarkPosition.TopLeft => 0,
                                     WaterMarkPosition.TopRight => 0,
                                     WaterMarkPosition.BottomLeft => uploadedImage.Height - watermarkHeight,
                                     WaterMarkPosition.BottomRight => uploadedImage.Height - watermarkHeight,
                                     WaterMarkPosition.TopMiddle => 0,
                                     WaterMarkPosition.BottomMiddle => uploadedImage.Height - watermarkHeight,
                                     _ => (uploadedImage.Height - watermarkHeight) / 2, 
                                 };

                                 graphic.DrawImage(watermarkImage, new Rectangle(x, y, watermarkWidth, watermarkHeight), 0, 0, watermarkImage.Width, watermarkImage.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, watermarkAttributes);

                                 using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                                 {
                                     mergedImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                                     var imageData = ms.ToArray();
                                     try
                                     {
                                         var imageUrl = await _blobStorageService.UploadFileAsync(name, imageData);
                                         uploadedImagePaths.Add(imageUrl);
                                     }
                                     catch
                                     {
                                         throw new Exception("Strorage");
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

         return new Response<List<string>>(uploadedImagePaths);
     }
 }

While running this on the server I am getting this exception. I am not getting how to resolve this error.

"i am getting this exception" - what exception? You did not include it in the question.

What is the point of catching and throwing catch { throw new Exception("Strorage"); }? It just throws away all of your debug information with virtually nothing and causes an exception anyway. Why not just let the original exception be thrown?

The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception i am getting this exception sir

The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception this exception only i am getting
[HttpPost("image/upload")]
public async Task UploadImageAsync([FromQuery] UploadImageRequest request)
{
try
{
var response = await Mediator.Send(request);
       if (response.Succeeded)
       {
           return Ok(new { imageUrl = response.Data });
       }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       throw e;
   }

}here i am getting that exception

@BharatiHattikal - Where did you learn to do catch (Exception e) { throw e; }?

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27200

If you really want to add your context on your exception, you can catch (Exception e) { throw new Exception("msg", e); } to use original exception as inner exception.

Though your namespaces are not showing, here's the issue: You are working with something that has to do with System.Drawing and trying to deploy it to a Linux machine/Server.

Add the following to your csproj file:
<ItemGroup>
    <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>


Add the following line below the first line of code on your dockerfile (if you are using Docker):
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus



